# Generate Machine Key using power Shell - Unrecognized Command

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis, machine.config

I am trying to generate a machine key to place in my web configs, but its saying it is not recognized. I have already read the following question and use the same commands without success [Generate Machine Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846194/generate-machine-key-using-power-shell). Please check what am i doing:

I took the [Powershell Script](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/2915218#bookmark-appendixa) from microsoft site, then executed the commands below:

```
PS C:\> C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Docs\KeyGeneration\machinekey.ps1
```

Then

```
PS C:\> Generate-MachineKey -validationAlgorithm SHA1
```

It says that:

```
The term 'Generate-MachineKey' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try "dot sourcing" the running of the script, by placing a period and then a space before the script

PS C:> . C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Docs\KeyGeneration\machinekey.ps1

Comment: Indeed; just to add some explanation: Because the OP did _not_ "dot-source" the script invocation, the function inside the script was defined in a _child_ scope that went away when the script exited.