# Generated shell script doesn't output anything

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis

I have the following powershell script from original source. It is used for generating a machine key for validation of the viewstate MAC. However, when I run it in Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\Documents> .\Generate-MachineKey.ps1 -decryptionAlgorithm AES -validationAlgorithm SHA1
```

Nothing is being output, the following is the script. What is the reason that nothing is output.

```
 function Generate-MachineKey {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [ValidateSet("AES", "DES", "3DES")]
    [string]$decryptionAlgorithm = 'AES',
    [ValidateSet("MD5", "SHA1", "HMACSHA256", "HMACSHA384", "HMACSHA512")]
    [string]$validationAlgorithm = 'HMACSHA256'
  )
  process {
    function BinaryToHex {
        [CmdLetBinding()]
        param($bytes)
        process {
            $builder = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
            foreach ($b in $bytes) {
              $builder = $builder.AppendFormat([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, "{0:X2}", $b)
            }
            $builder
        }
    }
    switch ($decryptionAlgorithm) {
      "AES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider }
      "DES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider }
      "3DES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider }
    }
    $decryptionObject.GenerateKey()
    $decryptionKey = BinaryToHex($decryptionObject.Key)
    $decryptionObject.Dispose()
    switch ($validationAlgorithm) {
      "MD5" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACMD5 }
      "SHA1" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 }
      "HMACSHA256" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 }
      "HMACSHA385" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA384 }
      "HMACSHA512" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512 }
    }
    $validationKey = BinaryToHex($validationObject.Key)
    $validationObject.Dispose()
    [string]::Format([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
      "<machineKey decryption=`"{0}`" decryptionKey=`"{1}`" validation=`"{2}`" validationKey=`"{3}`" />",
      $decryptionAlgorithm.ToUpperInvariant(), $decryptionKey,
      $validationAlgorithm.ToUpperInvariant(), $validationKey)
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39576902/45375 is closely related, but not quite a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Because by calling script file in your command you actually do not call the function `Generate-MachineKey` inside the script.

Correct way in your case would be *"dot source"* the script file and then call the function contained within the script:

```
. .\Generate-MachineKey.ps1
Generate-MachineKey -decryptionAlgorithm AES -validationAlgorithm SHA1
```

Please read [dot sourcing Powershell scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-6#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) for more details and understand the difference between scripts, functions, calling and dot sourcing concepts

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the script, but no the function inside.  Add a call to your function at the end of the script:

```
Generate-MachineKey -decryptionAlgorithm AES  -validationAlgorithm SHA1
```

Alternatively, you can take the code out of the function and just have the 'param' section as the parameters definition for the script instead.